# What is optimal way of storing Javascript Number in PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, precision

I have numbers generated from Javascript code and I want to store them in PostgreSQL table. I have legacy table where the whole JSON object is stored as JSONB type and in the new table I'd like to flatten the JSON to separate columns.

Ideally I want to avoid loss of precision as much as possible. Especially I'd like to avoid turning JS integer numbers into float numbers and vice versa. In other words inserting integer and getting back float is something I'd like to mitigate (if possible).

So far I've experimented with `DOUBLE PRECISION` and `NUMERIC` types. I think `NUMERIC` is better fit because documentation states that within the implementation limits there is no loss in precision. On the other hand `DOUBLE PRECISION` will be probably faster for numeric operations. I plan to do a lot of statistical operations.

I am not sure which one to choose. What is the optimal or recommended PostgreSQL data type with regards to maximum compatibility JavaScript Number type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not JavaScript expert, but what I found on [net](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp), then JavaScript uses 64bit floats. It is same like `DOUBLE PRECISION` type - 8bytes like 8bytes.

Comment: That clears things up. For some reason I though JavaScript is not using IEEE 754 and it didn't occur to me to do the search... Thanks.